# Looping through and editing text files from R

Tags: r, paste

I have a list of text files:

```
> filenames
[1] "meanimpactscript.inp"      "measinvarscript_IBR1.inp"  "measinvarscript_IBR10.inp" "measinvarscript_IBR13.inp"
[5] "measinvarscript_IBR2.inp"  "measinvarscript_IBR4.inp"  "measinvarscript_IBR5.inp"  "measinvarscript_IBR7.inp" 
[9] "varimpactscript.inp"
```

I would like to apply the following code to each of the files. Would appreciate any help.

```
meanimpactscript <- readLines("meanimpactscript.inp")
ix <- grep("ETA BY IBR13" , meanimpactscript) 
p <- paste(append(meanimpactscript, "thresholds", ix), collapse = "\n")
writeLines(p, con="meanimpactscript.inp")
```

Comment: There are a couple ways you could approach this. A `for` loop or `lapply` on a custom function are two options. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I ended up doing it successfully with a for loop. Thanks for the input though!